# Permission denied error with gulp-sftp to directory with Basic AuthType

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, web, web-development-server

I'm using a gulp task to upload my built files to a web server with the **gulp-sftp** plugin. However, I'm now getting an error since basic authentication was added to the `remotePath` directory on the test site (in the form of an `.htaccess` file).

Here's my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('upload', function() {
    gulp.src('./build/**/*')
        .pipe(sftp({
            host: 'example.com',
            auth: 'keyMain',
            remotePath: '/var/www/dest',
            callback: uploadComplete
        }));
});
```

And here is the error I'm now getting when I run the same task:

```
[13:42:34] Authenticating with password.
[13:42:35] SFTP error or directory exists: Error: Failure /var/www/dest
events.js:85
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Permission denied
    at SFTP._parse (...)
    ...
```

The SFTP credentials differ from the Basic AuthType ones and my `.ftppass` file only contains the SFTP credentials.

Here's what my `.ftppass` file looks like:

```
{
    "keyMain": {
        "user": "<my SFTP username>",
        "pass": "<my SFTP password>"
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I need to pass through the Basic AuthType credentials to fix this error. Can anyone help?

Cheers :)

PS: I'm using:

- Mac OS X 10.11.1
- Node v0.12.7
- Gulp CLI version 3.9.0
- gulp-sftp ^0.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem: it was with an existing `index.html` file that my gulp task was not able to overwrite. When I manually deleted that file (with an FTP client) and retried my gulp task, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when I had the wrong path. I was fooled by the entry (home) directory when connecting with a traditional FTP client. You want to just reference directly from the root with `/`

Instead of `../../myPath/html`

I needed `/myPath/html`